# how to reload a page with ?parameter=only link and replace the current anchor page in Jquery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, refresh, multilingual

That sounds complicated, doesn't it... actually it's quite easy:

I have a multi-language app and changing languages requires to reload the page.

I want users to
a) be able to change languages **without rel="external"ing the link** (restarting the app)
b) do this from any page, so my link will only include the language parameter **?lang=EN**

I have been fiddling with this forever, also getting some help from [JQM devs](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4253) and trying to stick close to this [example](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-dynamic.html) on dynamic pages from the JQM docs.

The following solutions works so-so. See my question below:

```
$(document).on( "pagebeforechange.lang", function( e, data ){
    // just strings
    if (typeof data.toPage === "string") {  
        if (data.toPage.indexOf("?lang=") > -1) {
            console.log("language change")
            // stop here
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            var toUrl = $.mobile.path.parseUrl( data.toPage );
                viewSwitch  = toUrl.search.replace( /.*lang=/, "" ),
                form = "",
                service = "some_coldfusion_cfc_to_load_new_language.cfc",
                method = "locale",
                returnformat = "JSON",
                targetUrl = toUrl.filename,
                // fake submit
                formdata = "form_submitted=lang&viewSwitch="+viewSwitch+"&method="+method+"&returnformat="+returnformat,
                successHandler = function() {       

                    alert("changed language successfully")
                    // now we changepage
                    $.mobile.changePage( targetUrl, { 
                        reloadPage: true,
                        transition: "fade",
                        allowSamePageTransition: true
                        });
                    };
            // send AJAX to update language server side    
            // page will reload on success
            ajaxFormSubmit( form, service, formdata, targetUrl, successHandler );
            }
        } 
    });
```

Ok. This works, but... the page is added as a new page to the DOM (with data-external-page="true", so when I click the next page, the page will be removed.

**Question**:
How do I make this reloaded page the new "anchor" page = the page that stays in the DOM? I can remove *data-external-page*, but what other things do I need to do? Set Base?...

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reload a page pretty easily using `$.mobile.changePage()` as long as you are reloading an external page (not a pseudo-page of a multi-page template):

```
$.mobile.changePage('myPage.cfm?lang=EN', {
    reloadPage : true
});
```

This will request a new page from your server which can output the content in whatever language is selected, then removes the current version of this page in the DOM and finally adds the new version to the DOM.

Documentation for `reloadPage` flag: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/methods.html

Comment: It's an external page, but if I only have a link like ?lang=EN (no myPage.cfm), JQM doesn't remove the original page, which was my problem to start with - it adds it to the DOM again, so I had the German and English version of the same page in the DOM. I could revert to using Coldfusion #CGI.PATH#+lang=EN, which inserts the current path into the link, so the link in a template would be flexible), but I thought there must be a way to do this JQM only. At least only providing link parameters should tell JQM "mh, maybe this is the same page :-)". Try $.mobile.path.parseUrl on ?para=only...

Comment: Little late... I'm sticking with an interim solution and have the same page in the DOM twiche. One in default language, the other one loaded by the user when changing languages. I keep the language on the server, so when the user goes to another page, my translated start page will be replaced with an translated "another page". If I ever find a way to replace the default languag page with the translated page without rel=external, I will re-post. As usual, THANKS for your great input!